# Monkey Patch jquery function contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to monkeypatch an existing javascript function so that one of its lines point to a new location. It would be easy to just redefine the function, except that it is rendered from server side code that has dynamic contents in it.

```
function GoPrint() {
    $.cookie('edit_child','on',{expires:28,path:'/'}); //Dynamically created (edit child could be off)
    window.open('../../Common/Output/HTMLtoPDF.aspx','print'); //Always static, need to change this call.
}
```

In my example, the first line creating the cookie, is created dynamically server side, so the property could be set to off.

I need to the change the window.open to call a different page instead of the htmltopdf page.

Although nasty, I would like to just redefine the function with a replace on the HTMLtoPDF text to point to the new page.

I have started this below, but do not know how to get the existing contents of the function to change it.

```
function($){

            var _oldPrint = $.fn.GoPrint;

            $.fn.GoPrint = function(arg1,arg2){
                   return _oldPrint.call(this,'',);
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to call `toString` on the old function, sub the old URL out with the new one, and eval the result, but only after considering the security implications.

Purely security-wise, a safer way would be to monkey patch the `window.open` function inside the monkey patch of `GoPrint`.

```
function($) {

  var _oldPrint = $.fn.GoPrint;

  $.fn.GoPrint = function(arg1, arg2) {
    var _oldopen = window.open;

    window.open = function() {
      _oldopen.call('YOUR_URL_HERE', 'print');
    };

    return _oldPrint.call(this);

    window.open = _oldopen;
  };
})(jQuery);
```